Simulating key press as input for function
In mu4e mode you can toggle some properties via the function mu4e-search-toggle-property. More specifically, after calling this function, you can (de-)activate "Full-search", "Include-related", "Show threads", "Skip duplicates" and "Hide-predicate" by typing f, r, t, u and p, respectively.
By default "Show threads" is on. Since I don't want my emails to be shown as threads, I have to enter M-x mu4e-search-toggle-property followed by typing t each time I start up mu4e, which is tedious. (Thanks to key bindings, typing Pt would be enough, but this is still annoying.)
For this reason, I want to change my configuration file to automatically toggle off threading. However, I miserably fail at simulating the t key press. So far, I have tried something like
(defun test ()
   (ineractive)
    (mu4e-search-toggle-property (kbd "t")))

which shows no effect.
How is it possible to simulate pressing t after invoking this function? And why is the code snippet above ineffective?

Likely a duplicate question. Check the source code for the command, to see what its interactive spec does with the t input - what value it passes to the function body. Then call the function with that value.

Following Drew's comment I looked into the source code which shows that M-x mu4e-search-toggle-property t toggles the variable mu4e-search-threads, so adding (setq mu4-search-threads nil) to my configuration file does the trick. (Still wondering though why it isn't possible to somehow simulate pressing t as indicated in my question.)

"Still wondering though why it isn't possible to somehow simulate pressing t as indicated in my question." - I may be wrong, but I think it's impossible, because the t is not passed as an argument to the function. It is instead read by mu4e-read-option which is called by mu4e-search-toggle-property in order to set a local variable, choice. I don't see any way to do that from the outside.

Maybe you can push a t back into the input buffer, so the read will get it, but that looks pretty yucky to me. See Miscellaneous Event Input Features but consider it a last resort only. Your answer is the way to go.
